# React: capturing form values that were not changed

Tags: reactjs

In the tutorials I've found, the best way to capture forms inputs, is to use a "onchange" handler.
However, how should we deal with fields that are left to the default value ?

For example in something like the example below, if "country" is left to the default value, the "formData" will never get it.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer, {});

const handleChange = event => {
    setFormData({
        name: event.target.name,
        value: event.target.value,
    });
}

const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    };
    fetch('http://0.0.0.0:8000/add_user/', requestOptions)
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onChange={handleChange} />
    <input type="text" name="country" value="" onChange={handleChange} required />
  </fieldset>
  <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</form>
```

I've thought about some solutions but I don't think they are the best practices. For example, adding a snippet of code that manually assigns all default values to the form in the construction, so the formData is pre-filled.
Is there a clean & nice way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `useReducer` hook you should store initial country value and then assign it to the value in country input, like below:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer, { country: "" });

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
 <fieldset>
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onChange={handleChange} />
   <input type="text" name="country" value={formData.country} onChange={handleChange} required />
 </fieldset>
 <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. but what if I have a dynamically generated list of inputs (based on existing data) ? For example 5 sets of (name, country). The input names will be (name0, country0), (name1, country1)... The only working way I found was adding 'formData[key+"|name"]=name' after rendering each input. But not great

Comment: Meaning that, the form is pre-filled with data coming from an API. So:
1: query API
2: generate form with pre-filled values (from API)
3: submit form, taking all values into account, including the ones that have not changed.
I tried your solution, but at the time "formData" is initialized, the API data is not there yet, so it cannot be used to initalize it